# Combine custom numeric format string with hex format string

Tags: .net, formatting, string-formatting

I have a situation where I need to format an integer differently depending on whether or not it's zero. Using custom numeric format strings, this can be achieved with the semicolon as a separator. Consider the following:

```
// this works fine but the output is decimal
string format = "{0:0000;-0000;''}";
Console.WriteLine(format,  10); // outputs "0010"
Console.WriteLine(format, -10); // outputs "-0010"
Console.WriteLine(format,   0); // outputs ""
```

However, the format that I want to use is hex. What I would like the output to be is more like:

```
// this doesn't work
string format = "{0:'0x'X8;'0x'X8;''}";
Console.WriteLine(format,  10); // desired "0x0000000A", actual "0xX8"
Console.WriteLine(format, -10); // desired "0xFFFFFFF6", actual "0xX8"
Console.WriteLine(format,   0); // desired "", actual ""
```

Unfortunately, when using a custom numeric format string, I am not sure how (if it's even possible) to use the hex representation of the number in the custom format string. The scenario I have doesn't permit much flexibility so doing a two-pass format isn't an option. Whatever I do needs to be represented as a String.Format style format string.

**EDIT**
After looking over the Mono source for NumberFormatter (the .NET implementation simply defers to internal unmanaged code) I've confirmed my suspicions. The hex format string is treated as a special case and it is only available as a standard format string and cannot be used in a custom format string. And since a three part format string can't be used with a standard format string, I'm pretty much S.O.L.

I will probably just bite the bullet and make the integer property a nullable int and use nulls where I was using zero - bleh.

Comment: What happens when you try the hex format?

Comment: I updated the question with the actual output of the 2nd format. But basically, it treats the X8 (which is a valid standalone format string) as a literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following format string is ALMOST correct:

```
string format = "0x{0:X8}";
Console.WriteLine(format, 10);
Console.WriteLine(format, -10);
Console.WriteLine(format, 0);
```

gives:

> 0x0000000A
>
> 0xFFFFFFF6
>
> 0x00000000

I'm still trying to work the '' for 0.

EDIT: I am having the same issue, with the X8's becoming literals only when the format string has the seperator ';' in use. I'm just going to poke around in the .NET source and see what I can see.

EDIT 2: The follow extension method will return a string with the correct formatting, both for +'ves, -'ves and 0. The parameter length is the amount of characters required in the hex string (excluding the '0x' on the front).

```
    public static string ToHexString(this int source, int length)
    {
        return (source != 0) ? string.Format("0x{0:X" + length.ToString() + "}",source) : string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I've been trying to do the same but I think the unfortunate reality is that the standard format string for hex is a special case that can't be reproduced with a custom format string.

Comment: It appears so. I've update the answer with a small extension method that will format an int based on the rules given.

Comment: Thanks, but the formatting of the number to string is out of my hands so I can't use an extension method or IValueConverter, etc. All I can do is provide a string format to format the output. Using the 3-part custom format string I can make zeros appear as empty strings but unfortunately it looks like I'm stuck with decimal display for non-zero values.

Comment: Fair enough. Odd things like this frustrate me so often.